# CakePHP custom ACL Authorization using acos, aros & aros_acos Acl tables with extension api_

Tags: php, api, cakephp, acl, croogo

I am developing an restful API using CakePHP, I am trying to implement a custom authorization which authorize user using ACL, code looks something like

```
<?php
App::uses('BaseAuthorize', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class ApiAuthorize extends BaseAuthorize {
     public function authorize($user, CakeRequest $request) { 
                $allowed = false;
        $Acl = $this->_Collection->load('Acl'); 
        list($plugin, $userModel) = pluginSplit($this->settings['userModel']);
        $action = $this->action($request); 

        $cacheName = 'permissions_' . strval($user['id']); 
        if (($permissions = Cache::read($cacheName, 'permissions')) === false) {
            $permissions = array(); 
            Cache::write($cacheName, $permissions, 'permissions');
        }
        if (!isset($permissions[$action])) {
            $User = ClassRegistry::init($this->settings['userModel']);
            $User->id = $user['id'];
            $allowed = $Acl->check($User, $action); 
            $permissions[$action] = $allowed;
            Cache::write($cacheName, $permissions, 'permissions');
            $hit = false;
        } else {
            $allowed = $permissions[$action];
            $hit = true;
        }
            return $allowed;
     }
}
```

I am using same database for website(developed using croogo) and API so my database already has `acos`, `aros` & `aros_acos` tables of website so for API I am created ACL tables with api_ extension like `api_acos`, `api_aros` & `api_aros_api_acos`

New schema of my ACL tables are

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api_acos` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `foreign_key` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `lft` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rght` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api_acos_api_aros` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `api_aro_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `api_aco_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_create` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `_read` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `_update` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `_delete` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api_aros` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `foreign_key` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `lft` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rght` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I am using custom ACL class from here https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/Authorize/blob/master/Controller/Component/Acl/HabtmDbAcl.php

My question is where and how can I use my new database tables (`api_acos`, `api_aros` & `api_aros_api_acos`) for ACL lookup? Please point me to code from where I can take reference for custom ACL Authorization implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just reuse the existing acl tables from Croogo with a different root node for API.

This is what the Croogo core is doing too.  Unfortunately, the install data does not provide this by default.

You can create the `api` root node by running the `Acl.extras` shell:

```
$ Console/cake acl.extras aco_sync

Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.1 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : croogo-app
Path: /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Skipped Aco node: controllers/Croogo/CroogoError
Created Aco node: controllers/Extensions/ExtensionsDashboard
Created Aco node: controllers/Extensions/ExtensionsDashboard/admin_index
Created Aco node: controllers/Extensions/ExtensionsPlugins/admin_moveup
Created Aco node: controllers/Extensions/ExtensionsPlugins/admin_movedown
Created Aco node: controllers/Menus/Links/admin_link_chooser
Created Aco node: controllers/Menus/Menus/admin_toggle
Created Aco node: controllers/Meta/Meta
Created Aco node: controllers/Meta/Meta/admin_delete_meta
Created Aco node: controllers/Meta/Meta/admin_add_meta
Created Aco node: api/v1_0/Nodes/Nodes/lookup
Created Aco node: api/v1_0/Users/Users/lookup
Created Aco node: controllers/Wysiwyg
Aco Sync Complete
```

You can manually add the necessary ACOs as per your API requirements, or use the ApiComponent as a base which will enable the extras shell to auto-create it for your later.

The `UserApiComponent` and `NodeApiComponent` can provide some example on how to implement API methods.